# surface charge density $\hat{\rho}$ and surface current density $\hat{\mathbf{j}}$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, notation, boundary-conditions

I am currently studying the textbook *Principles of Optics: Electromagnetic Theory of Propagation, Interference and Diffraction of Light*, 7th edition, by Max Born and Emil Wolf. Page 5, chapter **1.1.3 Boundary conditions at a surface of discontinuity**, says the following:

> Instead of the volume charge density $\rho$ the concept of *surface charge density* $\hat{\rho}$ must then be used. It is defined by
> $$\lim_{\delta h \to 0} \int \rho \ dV = \int \hat{\rho} \ dA. \tag{17}$$
> We shall also need later the concept of *surface current density* $\hat{\mathbf{j}}$, defined in a similar way:
> $$\lim_{\delta h \to 0} \int \mathbf{j} \ dV = \int \hat{\mathbf{j}} \ dA \tag{18}$$

In the notation that I am accustomed, the hat symbol on a vector usually means that it is a unit vector. However, reading [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density#Continuity_equation), I don't think that $\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ is a unit vector? Also, $\rho$ is a constant, so it wouldn't make sense if the hat symbol was to denote a unit vector. I would appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: It’s probably just a (rather poor in my opinion) choice of notation.

Comment: @LvdT Yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: Don't get hung up on notation.  The intention of the author is clear by the mathematical expressions.   Different people use different notation; there is no universal standard.   BTW, this question and your other one make me wonder if you are just starting a study of optics.  If so,  Born and Wolf is the hard way.

Comment: @garyp Haha, I started with Hecht and was told that *it* was "the hard way".

Comment: B & W Is a wonderful book that was written before the notation of using a hat for unit vector was adopted.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In addition to that, it was written before the era of high speed calculation.  So much of the text is devoted to ways of developing techniques of approximation and efficiency of calculation.  These parts are certainly not relevant to someone just starting out.  Born and Wolf is indeed a wonderful book that I've gone to many times.  But it's not a place to start.  It's for professionals and grad students.